# Não consegui entender o new cpaint()

Tags: javascript

O código abaixo não entendi o que significa:

```
var cp = new cpaint();
    cp.set_response_type('text');
    cp.set_debug(false);
    cp.call('../../atd/asp/atd0027m_crossbrowser.asp', 'BuscarPrestadorNome', ExibePrestadorNome, sNomePrestador, sCodOperadora, sCodUnidade);
```

Qual o tipo da var `cp`?

Comment: Dê uma olhada [neste link](http://cpaint.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: O tipo será `object`. JS não é C#, então existem poucos tipos. Tem alguma dúvida mais específica ou é só isto que deseja saber?

Comment: @bigown, o que não consegui realmente entender foi o cp.call. Qual função ou algo ele está chamando? Devido ao que eu estou fazendo aqui, fiquei voando.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno, ok, ao chegar em casa caso não encontrando uma resposta aqui, irei dar uma olhada. Aqui na empresa esse link é bloqueado por política de segurança.

Comment: @CesarMiguel, aqui está normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se responde à pergunta, mas deve esclarecer o funcionamento da palavra chave `new`.

Essa é a maneira de simular orientação a objetos em javascript. O tipo da variável `cp`  será `object` devido ao `new`, mas o seu conteúdo pode ser feito de duas maneiras.

Uma das definições retorna um objeto "interface", com métodos e atributos públicos e a outra não retorna nada, o código é auto-explicativo e os comentários complementam.

```js
var lib_exemplo = function() { // não retorna nada
  var variavel_privada = 'foo';
  this.variavel_publica = 'bar'; // vinculada ao "this"
  this.funcao = function() { // pública
    return variavel_privada;
  }
}

ex1 = new lib_exemplo();
console.log(ex1.variavel_privada); // undefined
console.log(ex1.variavel_publica); // "bar"
console.log(ex1.funcao()); // "foo"

var lib_exemplo_2 = function() {
  var self = this; // variável para acesso interno
  var variavel_privada = 'foo';
  this.variavel_privada_2 = 'bar';
  this.variavel_privada_3 = 'foobar';
  // definições com "var" e "this" são privadas, muda a forma de acesso

  return { // retorna "interface" - métodos e atributos publicos
    variavel1: variavel_privada,
    variavel2: this.variavel_privada_2,
    funcao: function() {
      // "this" dentro na função na interface se refere à interface
      // então use "self"
      return self.variavel_privada_3;
    }
  }
}

ex2 = new lib_exemplo_2();
console.log(ex2.variavel_privada); // undefined
console.log(ex2.variavel_privada_2); // undefined
console.log(ex2.variavel1); // "foo"
console.log(ex2.variavel2); // "bar"
console.log(ex2.funcao()); // "foobar"
```

**Observação:** Dentro das bibliotecas de exemplo acima `this` se refere ao contexto criado com `new`, chamar a função sem `new` não vai gerar o comportamento desejado.

Answer (score 1):

Vou tentar responder suas duas dúvidas.

Sempre que tiver dúvida, vale consultar a documentação do framework. Você disse o seguinte "o que não consegui realmente entender foi o cp.call" aqui está o link de toda a descrição do que o método call faz http://cpaint.sourceforge.net/doc/frontend.class.cpaint.call.html.

Quanto a dúvida "**Qual o tipo da var cp**"

Em javascript (como já foi dito) existem poucos tipos reservados. É bem diferente de linguagens compiladas como C#, Java e etc.

Então o tipo da var cp seria "**object**", faça um teste simples para comprovar isso.

```js
function Carro() {
  var teste = "";
}

var meucarro = new Carro();

console.log(typeof meucarro);
```

A reposta vai ser "object" e não Carro (como seria em muitas linguagens como java e C# por exemplo).

Porém dentro da variável **meucarro** existe um instância de Carro. Em outras palavras, a variável **meucarro** possui os mesmo comportamentos de Carro, sendo possível fazer uso de todos seus métodos e operações.

Espero ter te ajudado.