# Encapsulamento em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis

Se crio uma variável JavaScript global, ela pode ser facilmente acessada do console:

```
<script>
     var minhaVariavel = 0;
<script>
```

Mas se eu crio ela assim:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function (){ 
          var minhaVariavel = 0; 
     });
<sctip>
```

É possível de alguma forma acessá-la ou ela está realmente segura?

Preciso de uma forma de não deixar que minha variável seja acessível ao console.

Comment: Relacionado: [Quando se deve usar var no javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2513/91)

Comment: Lembre-se que encapsulamento de código é algo que ajuda a escrever código correto. Encapsulamento não serve pra nada em questões de segurança porque o usuário pode substituir o seu código por outro se ele quiser (afinal, ele é que é o dono do computador)

Comment: relacionado ao conceito de encapsulamento: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85755/13561

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seguro é um termo relativo. Se quer saber se ela vai pipocar a qualquer momento em outro lugar e acessá-la sem querer, certamente está seguro.

Se quer saber se não há nenhum meio forçado (veja resposta do bfavaretto) e fora do normal de acessá-la, já não posso garantir. Mas aí por que faria isto?

Se está achando que o valor da variável ficará obscuro ou protegido e ninguém poderá vê-la, esqueça. Informação sensível não deve estar em um código JS, nem temporariamente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Irônico, ate ontem eu esta mesmo pensando um fazer uma pergunta sobre este assunto, e em relação a segurança do código encapsulado. Bom não é mais necessário.

Answer (score 3):

Como disse o Maniero, depende do seu conceito de segurança. Declarar a variável dentro de uma função impede que outros *scripts* leiam ou alterem seu valor. Porém, não impede que uma pessoa, munida de uma ferramenta de *debugging*, consiga fazer essas operações.

Dependendo também do que você faz no restante do código, a variável pode acabar acessível, por culpa sua. Toda função declarada dentro do seu `document.ready` terá acesso à variável. Se uma dessas funções altera o valor, e essa função por algum motivo acabar exposta no escopo global, um código externo poderia invocá-la e, indiretamente, alterar o valor da variável.

Answer (score 0):

O encapsulamento serve para ajudar as variáveis a não conflitarem durante a execução de sua aplicação e também não poluir o escopo global do browser. No entanto existe um padrão de design de código que auxilia o namespace e o encapsulamento e obfuscação de seu código Se quiser ver a resposta que ela recebe basta debugar o código que terá as respostas do que ela recebe.