# Função construtora e função dentro de função

Tags: javascript

Estou presso em uma questão de JavaScript que pede a distância entre dois pontos utilizando aquela fórmula d(p1,p2) = sqrt((x1-x2)² + (y1-y2)²). O problema é que se pede:

"Reescreva o exercício 5 utilizando objetos criados a partir de uma função construtora “Ponto”, o objeto ponto criado deve conter duas propri-
edades equivalentes aos valores de x e y e uma função que recebe outro
objeto ponto e retorna a distância entre eles."

Eis o meu código:

```
function Ponto(x,y){
  this.pontox = x;
  this.pontoy = y;
  this.calcula = function(p){
    aux1 = Math.pow(Ponto.x - p.x,2);
    aux2 = Math.pow(Ponto.y - p.y, 2);
    result = Math.sqrt(aux1+aux2,2);
    console.log(result);        
  }
}
ponto1 = new Ponto(0,0);
ponto2 = new Ponto(1,1);
ponto1.calcula(ponto2);
```

Só que o código só retorna `NaN`, e não o resultado em *float*, como eu gostaria. Já tentei passar os valores para *float*, mas não consegui resultados, então como fazer a função retornar o valor em *float*?

Comment: Notei um pouco de confusão quanto ao acesso das variáveis dentro da "classe", [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85755/13561) são explicados os escopos das variáveis e forma de acesso.

Answer (score 2):

Epifanio, uma dica, evite colocar a declaraçãod e funções no "construtor" da classe, ao invés disto, faça uso do prototype.

no mais você pode acessar as propriedades do objeto atual usando o `this`, então no lugar de `Ponto.x`, use `this.pontox`, ou melhor, renomeie ela para `this.x` apenas... afinão é meio redudante `Ponto.pontox`.

```js
var Ponto = function (x,y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

Ponto.prototype.calcula = function (pontoB) {
  var calc = {};
  calc.x = Math.pow(this.x - pontoB.x, 2);
  calc.y = Math.pow(this.y - pontoB.y, 2);
  return Math.sqrt(calc.x + calc.y, 2);
}

ponto1 = new Ponto(0,0);
ponto2 = new Ponto(1,1);

var distancia = ponto1.calcula(ponto2);
console.log(distancia);
```

Comment: legal, usando o `.prototype` o código fica mais limpo mesmo, tem algum outro motivo que incentive o uso?

Comment: @Sanção Prototype é mais eficiente tanto em uso de memória quanto de CPU (inclusive esse foi um dos motivos de sua inclusão em JavaScript). No exemplo original da questão a função `calcula` é criada toda vez que um `Ponto` é instanciado, já nesse exemplo com prototype `calcula` é definida apenas uma vez, logo na declaração, e todas as instancias compartilham a mesma implementação.